# How to make serialized array to save in database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to Save Serialized array in Mysql Database.

I want final result when save value in database looks like in below format:

```
a:1:{i:5;s:2:"2,";}
```

Please provide solution starting from how to make this kind of array and simple sql query (insert or update query).

Below is the code which i used:

```
<?php 
$a = array (
        '5' => '2,'
);

$b = serialize($a);
?>
```

and i use $b variable in sql query. But my data not save in my expected format.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not here to teach you how to use PHP or MySQL. Please do some work yourself, provide the code that you've tried and ask questions then.

Comment: Yes...i updated my question..#Richard

Comment: How do you try and save it???

Comment: Can you try to add your code with calling the insert query?

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you simple directions. Youll need to parse data from wherever you are passing from in Json format (object or an array).  Then in php use json_encode

And as # Richard said youll need to grasp these on your own then post some code youve tried but probably fails.